# Programatically how to connect to Office 365 Exchange by using PowerShell cmdlets from C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server, impersonation, office365

How do you do to manage the users in Office 365 Exchange and add a role like the `ApplicationImpersonation` using `PowerShell` `cmdlets` from c#? Any ideas? Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: See duplicate thread :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466038/is-it-possible-to-assign-roles-using-the-exchange-web-services-in-c/21725987#21725987](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466038/is-it-possible-to-assign-roles-using-the-exchange-web-services-in-c/21725987#21725987)