# Is it possible to assign roles using the Exchange web services in c#?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, impersonation, exchangewebservices, office365

Is it possible to assign roles using the Exchange web services in c#? Like you programatically automate of adding the role `ApplicationImpersonation` and assign the role to the users in Office 365 Exchange?

Answer (score 1):

Assigning roles using Exchange web services is not possible. If you wish to do this through a C# application, try executing PowerShell cmdlets in C#. Look for "RoleGroup" cmdlets.

This thread will give you some examples on how to execute PowerShell in C#:
[Powershell command through C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398171/powershell-command-through-c-sharp-code)